# Cannot show error message on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am facing a problem to show the error message by using $this->validate($request,[]);

**Route Post and Get**

```
Route::post('{phone}/{name}/store_location','RestaurantController@store_location'); 
Route::get('{phone}/{name}','RestaurantController@show');
```

**Store_location Controller**

```
public function store_location($phone, $name ,Restaurant_LocationRequest $request)
{   
    $this->validate($request, [
        'street'      => 'required',
        'city'        => 'required',
        'zip'         => 'required',
        'country'     => 'required',
        'state'       => 'required'
    ]);

    $restaurant_location = Restaurant::locatedAt($phone, $name)->first();

    $restaurant_location->restaurant_location()->create($request->all());

    return redirect($restaurant_location->phone . '/' . $restaurant_location->name);
}
```

**Form to show error**

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="/{{ $restaurant->phone }}/{{ $restaurant->name }}/store_location">

    @include('restaurant.create_restaurant_location_form')

    @if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

</form>
```

In this below is mine Request File
**Restaurant_LocationRequest Reques**

```
public function authorize()
{
        return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'street'      => 'required',
        'city'        => 'required',
        'zip'         => 'required',
        'country'     => 'required',
        'state'       => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$myErrors = $this->validate($request, [
        'street'      => 'required',
        'city'        => 'required',
        'zip'         => 'required',
        'country'     => 'required',
        'state'       => 'required'
    ]);

.............
...............

if($myErrors->fails()){
    return redirect($restaurant_location->phone . '/' . $restaurant_location->name)->withErrors($myErrors->errors());
}
```

Comment: It show error Call to a member function fails() on null

Comment: can you please provide some insight on Restaurant_LocationRequest?